# Increase Max Allocated Memory Golang 1.4+

Tags: go

I'm thinking about upgrading to Go 1.4 but am concerned because I no longer know how to change the max amount of memory I can address.
I have been using Go to run some machine learning experiments on a large server, 512GB of main memory, which makes the 128GB limit set using a 37 bit address insufficient.

Previously I would edit malloc.h in the runtime package to change to 38 bit addresses but with the conversion from C to Go of the source I'm having difficulty finding if there is still something as simple to modify.

This commit that changed max memory to 128GB from 16GB shows the kind of change I am talking about https://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=a310cb32c278

Comment: You might want to report this as a bug.

Comment: Maybe you better ask this on the mailing list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized I did not find the file because I am not use to using the Google Code repo explorer. I located what are now 3 malloc.go files and have found the relevant section of code.
https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/runtime/malloc2.go#122

Honestly I think the update using 1 and 0 booleans and multiplication rather than simple if statements is overly confusing and doesn't convey what is going on as clearly as the header file used to.

Also thank you bamboon I only realized my mistake after reading the mailing list and getting linked to a different repo viewer.

Comment: I just want to keep everyone up to date on this matter. The Go project as of the following commit supports 512GB by default on non-windows 64-bit platforms. https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/10819/4  I believe this will be part of 1.5 when it is released.